# Orchard signalr CryptographicException

Tags: signalr, orchardcms, cryptographicexception

I got this exception with Orchard with [SignalR 1.3.1 chat module](https://bitbucket.org/Proligence/proligence.signalr-git/wiki/Home) deploed on IIS on windows server 2008. It works fine in debug environment.

```
The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

 Source Error: 

 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

 [CryptographicException: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have     been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.]
 Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetRethrowWithNoStackLossDelegate>b__0(Exception ex) +42
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallContextAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +88
Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +42
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

The solution of same problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393684/signalr-cryptographicexception-on-azurewebsites), but I can not figure out how to apply it to the Orchard

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module has a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/Proligence/proligence.signalr-git/issue/1/iprotectdata-implementation).

You can fix this by adding to CoreModule.cs in `Load(ContainerBuilder moduleBuilder)` method line:

```
moduleBuilder.RegisterType<MachineKeyProtectedData>()
  .As<IProtectedData>();
```