# SignalR 2 fails on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr

I deployed an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 app on Azure, and ran into this problem with SignalR 2:
when starting connection from client, call to

```
/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B"name"%3A"gameHub"%7D%5D&_=1460028930688
```

fails with error 500.

The exception behind error 500 is this:

> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The data
>   protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by
>   not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user
>   context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [CryptographicException: The data protection operation was
>   unsuccessful. This may have     been caused by not having the user
>   profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the
>   case when the thread is impersonating.]

I read and tried solution suggested at [SignalR CryptographicException on AzureWebsites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393684/signalr-cryptographicexception-on-azurewebsites), but id didn't work for me.

As I understand, Azure doesn't allow LoadUserProfile.

Any workaround?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I've been trying to resolve this error also.  SignalR works fine localhost, but I deploy to azure and Internal 500 error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and my *fix* was to add a call to `UseAesDataProtectorProvider()` before my call to `MapSignalR()`. Hope this helps someone.